# How to Bind Parameter In String mysqli PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to bind a parameter in a LIKE statement in SQL using mysqli like so:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
$q = 'SELECT * from `books`';
if (!isblank($title) || !isblank($author) || !isblank($isbn)) {
  $q .= ' WHERE 1 = 1';
}
if (!isblank($title)) {
  $q .= ' AND `title` LIKE "%?%"';
}
if (!isblank($author)) {
  $q .= ' AND `author` LIKE "%?%"';
}
if (!isblank($isbn)) {
  $q .= ' AND `isbn` = ?';
}
echo $q;
if ($statement = $db->prepare($q)) {
  if (!isblank($title) && !isblank($author) && !isblank($isbn)) {
    $statement->bind_param('sss', $title, $author, $isbn);
  } else if (!isblank($title) && !isblank($author)) {
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $title, $author);
  } else if (!isblank($title) && !isblank($isbn)) {
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $title, $isbn);
  } else if (!isblank($author) && !isblank($isbn)) {
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $author, $isbn);
  } else if (!isblank($title)) {
    $statement->bind_param('s', $title);
  } else if (!isblank($author)) {
    $statement->bind_param('s', $author);
  } else {
    $statement->bind_param('s', $isbn);
  }
  if ($statement->execute()) {
    $statement->bind_result($returned_book); // hello carlo how are you today
    while ($statement->fetch()) {
      echo var_dump($returned_book);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that mysqli will states that there are not enough parameters to bind to because the `?` is in the string. If I get rid of the quotes (`$q .= ' AND`title`LIKE %?%';`) the parameter binds correctly but the SQL syntax is invalid. How can I bind to this LIKE query?

Comment: This looks pretty unmaintainable. If possible you should switch to PDO; there you can add elements to an array in the `if` conditions where you build the query. Then you simply send that array to the `execute` method. No conditional binding necessary although it would be possible using named parameters and repeating the initial conditions. A possible solution here would be to remove the quotes and `%`'s and add the `%`'s to your string values when you bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enclose the strings in SQL, use apostrophes instead of quotes. Quotes are not supported. In php wrap the string into quotes:

```
$q .= " AND `title` LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
```

Comment: This still causes binding to fail because the `?` is in the quotes

Comment: @cabellicar123 : You have to fix all the occurencies, I just gave an example how to fix.

Comment: yes I did so on both lines with quotes. I do not believe mysqli binds to `?` that are in quotes

Comment: You shouldn't use quotes when you use a prepared statement.

Comment: @cabellicar123 : Secondly, just actually have to do also the opposite - move `?` out of the quote string. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Binding doesn't work like copy and paste replace. You need to put the `?` in place of a ***value***. The value that you're binding then must contain the `%`:

```
$q = '... LIKE ?';

...

$theValue = "%$theValue%";
$statement->bind_param('s', $theValue);
```

Comment: This is the correct usage.. and, of course, it should be the accepted answer